# Axios request not working with React + Redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'll try to give a premise and then follow it up with the code.

I decided to implement Material UI into my React project, and I got most of it going. How the app is set up, the user is faced with the Login page. The Login.js module renders the [SignIn.js module](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/page-layout-examples/sign-in), enters their credentials, and clicks submit. The `formData`, `onChange` and `onSubmit` are passed as props to the SignIn component from the Login component -- and the Login component receives these via `mapStateToProps`. The Login component uses the connect middleware to link redux state to the react app.

Clicking submit triggers the formData (in the Login component which are passed to the SignIn component) to hit my `login` method located in `"../../actions/auth";`. The error occurs from within this method, at the axios call in the try catch, where I attempt to communicate with the backend `const response = await axios.post("/api/auth", body, config);`

What's weird is that `dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });` never gets hit, which is supposed to set the state to the token returned from the backend, as it seems that `LOGIN_SUCCESS` is never executed. But what's VERY weird is that console logging the token actually works! It just seems as through it's never stored, forcing AUTH_ERROR to get invoked instead.

This is my Login component:

```
 // Login.js
 import SignIn from "../../material/SignIn";

 const Login = ({ setAlert, login, isAuthenticated }) => {
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
 email: "",
 password: ""
 });

 const { email, password } = formData;

 const onChange = e => {
 setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
 };

 const onSubmit = e => {
 login(email, password);
 };
 // Redirect if logged in
 if (isAuthenticated) {
 return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
 }

 return (
 <Fragment>
      <SignIn
      email={email}
      password={password}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      onChange={onChange}
      isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
      />
 </Fragment>
 );
 };

 Login.propTypes = {
 setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
 };

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
 });

 export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 { setAlert, login }
 )(Login);
```

And the SignIn component that it is rendering is here:

```
 // SignIn.js
 export default function SignIn({ email, password, onChange, onSubmit }) {
 const classes = useStyles();

 return (
 <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
      <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
           <LockOutlinedIcon />
      </Avatar>
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
           Sign in
      </Typography>
      <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)} className={classes.form} noValidate>
           <TextField
           variant="outlined"
           margin="normal"
           required
           onChange={e => onChange(e)}
           fullWidth
           id="email"
           label="Email Address"
           name="email"
           value={email}
           // autoComplete="email"
           autoFocus
           />
           <TextField
           variant="outlined"
           margin="normal"
           required
           onChange={e => onChange(e)}
           fullWidth
           name="password"
           label="Password"
           type="password"
           value={password}
           id="password"
           autoComplete="current-password"
           />
           <FormControlLabel
           control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
           label="Remember me"
           />
           <Button
           type="submit"
           fullWidth
           variant="contained"
           color="primary"
           className={classes.submit}
           >
           Sign In
           </Button>
           <Grid container>
           <Grid item xs>
           <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
           </Link>
           </Grid>
           <Grid item>
           <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
           </Link>
           </Grid>
           </Grid>
      </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={5}>
      <MadeWithLove />
      </Box>
 </Container>
 );
 }
```

Clicking the submit button raises the `onSubmit` method in my Login component:

```
 // Login user
 export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
 // Config needed because we're sending data
 const config = {
 headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
 }
 };

 const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

 try {
 const response = await axios.post("/api/auth", body, config);

 // Skips over this dispatch
 dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: response.data
 });

 // But hits this dispatch.. and then console logs 'REACHED' as seen below
 dispatch(loadUser());
 } catch (err) {
 const errors = err.response.data.errors;

 if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => {
      dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger"));
      });
 }

 dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL
 });
 }
 };
```

If you notice, after the axios call, `loadUser is called`, defined as:

```
 // Load user
 export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {
 const token = localStorage.token;

 console.log('REACHED!'); // reached

 if (token) {
 setAuthToken(token);
 }

 try {
 const response = await axios.get("/api/auth");

 dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: response.data
 });
 } catch (err) {
 dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR // This is dispatched
 });
 }
 };
```

The backend route is the following:

```
 // @route  POST api/auth
 // @desc   Authenticate user and get token
 // @access Public
 router.post(
 "/",
 [
 check("email", "Please include a valid email").isEmail(),
 check("password", "Please is required").exists()
 ],
 async (req, res) => {
 const errors = validationResult(req);

 // send back any errors
 if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
      errors: errors.array()
      });
 }

 const { email, password } = req.body;

 try {
      // check if user exists, send error if so
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });

      if (!user) {
      return res
           .status(400)
           .json({ errors: [{ msg: "Invalid credentials" }] });
      }

      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

      if (!isMatch) {
      return res
           .status(400)
           .json({ errors: [{ msg: "Invalid credentials" }] });
      }
      // return jsonwebtoken so that way they're logged in right
      // away, without having to log in after registering
      const payload = {
      user: {
           id: user.id
      }
      };

      jwt.sign(
      payload,
      config.get("jwtSecret"),
      {
           expiresIn: process.env.PORT ? 3600 : 36000
      },
      (err, token) => {
           if (err) throw err;

           console.log(token); // prints token!

           return res.json({ token });
      }
      );
 } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Server error");
 }
 }
 );
```

I'm so confused at this point. The token is being rendered but it seems as though React doesn't 'await' the response before Node gets a chance to send it back.

Comment: what middleware are you using? It would need to support async actions.

Comment: You said "The error occurs..." but it is not very clear where and what error. Is it an error in the AJAX request? Or a JS exception? "logging the token actually works" where did you try to log the token?

Comment: @EricHasselbring Everything was working just fine before I decided to try to implement Material UI.

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala In the last function I posted in the question, in the `POST api/auth` in the JWT.sign. It seems as though the token is created in the backend, but is not returned in the `const response = await..` from the front end

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to explain this, but I solved it by getting rid of the onSubmit trigger from the form tag and placing it on the  in SignIn.js. I changed the type of the button to type button as well. Got it working :)